# Compare only DATE from 2 datetime columns - sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

How can I code to compare only the date (not time) from two different columns that is storing the date in 2015-01-10 01:20:00 format?
Example.

```
Select * from Admissions
Where AdmitDateTime = DepartDateTime
```

Above will try to compare 2015-01-10 01:20:00 to 2015-01-10 01:20:00 instead of only date 2015-01-10 to 2015-01-10.
Help Please.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way:

```
Select * from Admissions
Where DATEDIFF(dd,AdmitDateTime,DepartDateTime)=0
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why I was using 1 instead of 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from Admissions
Where CAST(AdmitDateTime as date) = CAST(DepartDateTime as date)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert or cast a `DATETIME` data type to a `DATE` data type.

For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Admissions
WHERE 
CONVERT(DATE, AdmitDateTime) = CONVERT(DATE, DepartDateTime)
```